# C# Entity Generating Sequential number

Tags: c#, formatting

I am trying to generate Ref number in this format 0000001 if the Id is 1. I have a prefix F and the 00000 that will be overwritten from behind by the Id. The ID is autoIncrement

this is my approach but it is giving F-1 and so on I want F-0000001.

```
public class Function : BaseModel
{
    public Function()
    {
        Ref = Sequence;
    }

    [ForeignKey("Corporate")]
    public int CorporateId { get; set; }

    public virtual Corporate Corporate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }


    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public bool Approved { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Completed { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string ContactPersonPhone { get; set; }
    public string ContactPersonEmail { get; set; }
    public string Ref { get; set; }

    private string Sequence
    {
        get
        {
            var seq = "F" + "-" + Id;
            seq = seq.Replace(" ", "000000");
            return seq;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A side note - your question has nothing in common with `entity-framework`, please remove that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use String.Format with a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings):

```
String.Format("F-{0:0000000}", 1056)
```

Returns: `F-001056`

`0` is a zero placeholder `Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.`

The text outside the format item (`{0:...}`) is copied into the string as-is.

The property should look like this:

```
private string Sequence { get{ return String.Format("F-{0:0000000}", Id);}}
```

or

```
private string Sequence => String.Format("F-{0:0000000}", Id);
```

Comment: but not saving the the ID when i save only save the the zeroes

Answer (score 1):

Try using C#'s PadLeft function like this:

```
private string Sequence
{
    get
    {
        return "F-" + Id.ToString().PadLeft(6,"0");
    }
}
```

Comment: This generates 4 temporary strings without reason. A single call to `String.Format` will produce the desired string

Comment: This unfortunately wouldn't work, imagine if the ID was at 1000. the result would be :  "F-0000001000"

Comment: @PhillipMorton This answer isn't the best, but it would not work the way you describe.  The first parameter (`int totalWidth`) would only pad until that limit is hit, so for your proposed ID of 1000, the result of `PadLeft(6, '0')` would be "001000"

Answer (score 1):

Use [Int32.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx), passing the following format string in your property as follows:

```
private string Sequence => "F-" + Id.ToString("D7");
```

Change the "D7" to indicate how many zeroes to pad with.

Comment: This will still generate a temporary string. `String.Format` won't